# Jenkns Unable to Fetch From Github

Tags: jenkins, github

I am using the jenkins/jenkins:lts Docker image for Jenkins. I've configured my SSH keys on the Docker container and added the public key to my Github account. I am able to **clone** my Github repository from the Docker container.

My Jenkins job is configured to use Git; my branch is master. I've configured my credentials in Jenkins but when I run the job it hangs with the following error.

```
     Started by user Administrator
        Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test
        Cloning the remote Git repository
        Cloning repository git@github.com:xxx/stateAnsible.git
         > git init /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test # timeout=10
        Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:xxx/stateAnsible.git
         > git --version # timeout=10
        using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
         > git fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:xxx/stateAnsible.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:xxx/stateAnsible.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 143:
stdout: 
stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2016)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1735)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:420)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:629)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1146)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1819)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Please post your jenkins pipeline script

Comment: Thank you but not using a Pipeline script; not there, yet. All I'm trying to do at this point is to pull a Git repository through Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to copy and paste the private key into the credentials of the Jenkins user within Jenkins. I recall in the past that it'd use the keys in the default directory without having to do this? Odd.